# Super event on user interaction

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom-events

Is there a super event to trigger any user interaction?

I have an Anuglar App which I'd like to call a method when the user do the following things in the active window:

- Click
- Key-Up
- Scroll
- Select

Now I use something like this:

```
<div (click)="userDidSomething($event)" (keyup)="userDidSomething($event)" (scroll)="userDidSomething($event)">
```

I need something like this **Pseudo Code**:

```
<div (interaction)="userDidSomething($event)">
```

Is there an event like this?

Comment: You can create a directive which will listen to the events mentioned, and perform the action when any of those event took place. I have created a fork here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzauku where I have created a directive to listen to cut copy paste events and prevent those events. See block-cut-copy-paste.directive.ts file, [preventCutCopyPaste] is the directive name which is applied to one of the textbox in app.component.HTML page. You can create a directive in a similar way

Answer (score 0):

You could write an angular directive which handles events you need.
Directive appends to an element like attribute and you could attach an array of evens you need through bindings.

It might be helpful to follow this angular documentation
https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives